# PhantomJS 2.1.1 Error

Tags: phantomjs, karma-runner, angular5

I can't run my test with karma and phantomJS because of this error:

> PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7.0.0) ERROR
>     SyntaxError: Use of reserved word 'class'

Here is my config karma.conf.js:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular/cli'],
    plugins: [
        require('karma-jasmine'),
        require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
        require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
        require('karma-phantomjs-launcher'),
        require('@angular/cli/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client: {
        clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    files: [
        { pattern: './src/test.ts', watched: false }
    ],
    preprocessors: {
        './src/test.ts': ['@angular/cli']
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
        reports: ['html', 'lcovonly'],
        fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    angularCli: {
        environment: 'dev'
    },
    reporters: config.angularCli && config.angularCli.codeCoverage
        ? ['progress', 'coverage-istanbul']
        : ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_DEBUG,
    autoWatch: false,
    browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
    singleRun: true
});
};
```

I updated angular to v5 and it's happening since then... I read to use karma webpack preprocessor but I'm not using webpack and why was it running before ? No clue.

Thanks a lot if you have a tips or a response :)

Answer (score 1):

I am also facing the same problem after upgrading the angular8 to angular9.
After up-gradation to angular9 when I am trying to run ng test with PhantomJS it is showing

```
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 8.0.0) ERROR
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')'
```

but if I am trying with **ng test --browsers=Chrome --codeCoverage=true** it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

It runs fine with all `ES6` keywords, syntax etc.,
`PhantomJS` requires polyfills so install `core-js`, and import it before importing `zone`.

> import 'core-js/es6';